# config.js file in angular2 for the ckeditor?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

where is the config.js file for ckeditor (which i have installed using npm on the cli of vs code) situated? I have searched everywhere including my node modules but cannot seem to find it. Also, I have to remove some options namely the image and media uploader on the ckeditor top bar. Can someone please help me

thank you

Comment: Use `environment.ts` file

Comment: Why do you need config.js file? You should config ckeditor in component where are you using it.

Comment: Concerning the code for removing the image and media uploaders, do you have any idea on how to do it?

Comment: porgo, you mean to say in the ts file of that particular component?

Comment: @Ashna Yes. You can set there which buttons will be visible on editor toolbar.

Comment: @porgo do you have any code snippet for that please?

Comment: @Ashna I added an answer. I hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add your own config to ckeditor, you should use something like this:

html file:

```
<ckeditor [config]="config">
</ckeditor>
```

and in ts file you should create `config` object:

```
this.config = {
  toolbar: [
    ['Maximize'],
    ['Format', 'FontSize'],
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'RemoveFormat'],
    ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
    ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
    ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
    ['Table'],
    ['Cut', 'Copy'],
    ['Link', 'Unlink'],
    ['Undo', 'Redo']
  ]
};
```

This example shows how to config buttons which are available in toolbar.

You can also read about integration with angular for example here:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_angular.html

Comment: i just tried the code but its still not working. i have added the config object in my ngoninit method but still in vain

Comment: @Ashna what exactly is not working. Are you getting any errors or something? Are you using just ckeditor or have you also added ng2-ckeditor?

Comment: no, I'm not getting any errors 
i'm just using the ckeditor